# Using definite integration to find the area enclosed by a curve

Tags: definite-integrals

Say you have the curve $y=x^3-5x^2+6x$ with roots 0, 2 and 3. Integrating $y$ I got the equation $\frac14x^4-\frac53x^3+3x^2+C$. I found the value of $C$ by subbing a point form the curve such as $(0,2)$ and found the value for $C$ to be $-\frac83$, after which I found that
$\int_0^2y\,dx=\frac83$ and $-\int_2^3y\,dy=\frac5{12}$. Adding them up gave the area as $\frac{37}{12}$, however the answer is $\frac72$.

I am not entirely sure if the method and my answer is correct, or if the answer given is incorrect?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: which integral want you to solve?

Comment: I have been asked to prove that the area enclosed by the curve to the x axis is 3.5

Answer (score 0):

you will have the integral $$\int_{0}^{2}(x^3-5x^2+6x)dx+\left|\int_{2}^{3}(x^3-5x^2+6x)dx\right|$$
can you solve this?

Comment: That will give 8/3 but the answer is 3.5

Comment: yes indeed, are you sure that the given solution is right?

Comment: i have made a typo, now it is right

Comment: Now I get 37/12, which is what I got before, so does that mean that the answer that they have given is incorrect?

Comment: i think yes, it is incorrect, i got the same result

Comment: Ok thanks, for the help

Comment: wish you a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is $$37/12 = 3.08333...$$ which is what you have found.